# Make a player in unity3d move based on the camera?

Tags: javascript, c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a third person player, and right now I have everything set up apart from one problem, the player always moves to the same directions when moving, no matter where the camera is facing, which makes the movement very difficult.

My player controller:

```
public class Character_Controler : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 6f;
private bool canJump = false;
    Vector3 movement;
    Rigidbody playerRbody;

    void Awake()
    {
        playerRbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
        {
    playerRbody.AddForce(Physics.gravity * playerRbody.mass);
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        var jump = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
    if (!canJump && playerRbody.velocity.y == 0)
    {
        canJump = true;

    }
        if (jump&& canJump == true)
    {
        playerRbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 6f, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
        canJump = false;
    }
    if (h != 0 || v != 0 && !jump) Move(h,v);
}

        void Move (float h, float v)

    {
    movement.Set(h, 0f, v);
    movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    playerRbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
    playerRbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
    }



}
```

Camera's controller(I didn't make this):

```
      var target : Transform;
var distance = 10.0;
var xSpeed = 250.0;
var ySpeed = 120.0;

var yMinLimit = -20;
var yMaxLimit = 80;

private var x = 0.0;
private var y = 0.0;

@script AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Orbit")

function Start () {
var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
x = angles.y;
y = angles.x;

// Make the rigid body not change rotation
if (GetComponent.<Rigidbody>())
    GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
}

function LateUpdate () {
if (target) {
    x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02;
    y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02;

    y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

    var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
    var position = rotation * Vector3(0.0, 2.0, -distance) + target.position;

    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = position;
}
}

static function ClampAngle (angle : float, min : float, max : float) {
if (angle < -360)
    angle += 360;
if (angle > 360)
    angle -= 360;
return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
}
```

Comment: sounds like your moving based on a global space instead of local, I have a script for this back at home, but if you don't feel like waiting check youtube you'll find a good tutorial

Comment: Your not using your transforms forward to tell it the direction to move look at the example in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) `rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: Do you always want the camera to follow the player?

Comment: @johnny5
So I change my move event to this:
            `void Move (float h, float v)

        {
        transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        movement.Set(h, 0f, v);
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerRbody.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * speed);
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
        playerRbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
        }`
And now the player does move depending on where the came is, but he only moves forward, even if you press any wasd key

Comment: @trahane Yes, and the camare alread is following him, it's just that the player isn't moving left/right forward/backward depending on where it's facing.